# Is there a way to conditionally use @StateObject while targeting iOS 13?

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app that is targeting iOS 13 and higher. I would like to conditionally use the `@StateObject` property wrapper if I am running on iOS 14, as it would fix so many bugs I've had to workaround on iOS 13.

Is there any way to conditionally do this via `#ifdef` or `#if available(iOS 14, *)` calls or similar? I'm happy to have a completely separate implementation of a given view for iOS 14.

I've tried this but it of course doesn't compile.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel()
    } else {
        @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the `@available` attribute like so:

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {}

@available(iOS 14, *)
struct FourteenView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text("iOS 14")
    }
}

struct ThirteenView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text("iOS 13")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            AnyView(FourteenView())
        } else {
            ThirteenView()
        }
    }
}
```

This only works in Xcode 12 of course. I'm using 12.0 beta 3 (12A8169g).

The `AnyView()` in the `ContentView` is because using `if #available(iOS 14, *)` in a `@ViewBuilder` doesn't seem to work properly. See this [Apple Developer Forum thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650818).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use this StateObject that works on iOS 13:

https://gist.github.com/Amzd/8f0d4d94fcbb6c9548e7cf0c1493eaff